# Maven for Ubuntu ARM64

Tags: maven, arm64, pulsar

I have a Jetson Tx2 which is Ubuntu Linux ARM64.  I can't seem to find a 'binary' distribution for this.  Is my only option to get the source for Maven 3.3.9, build that and then build Maven 3.5 using the 3.3.9 version?

My ultimate goal is to get apache pulsar installed on this same platform.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Maven is distributed with native Jansi support in the form of dynamic link libraries for Freebsd 32/64, Linux 32/64. Windows 32/64 and Osx. This is the only dependency to native code I am aware of.
That is, you don't need to build Maven, you just have to download a 'binary' archive such as [this one](http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz), and to extract it - I am assuming here you already have a JDK for Aarch64 Linux installed.